# Trying to add WPHeader mark up in blogger template

Tags: xml, blogger, schema.org

I have a header code like this on my Blogspot template. and I want to add schema org mark up WPHeader

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='Header'>
      <b:section id='header2' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
      <b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='test (Header)' type='Header' version='1' >
      </b:widget>
      <b:includable id='title'>...</b:includable>
    </b:section>
</div>
```

I found articles which describe how to do this but in my  template, there isn't any header-wrapper
https://basic-blogger-template.readthedocs.io/en/latest/addingschemamarkup.html

```
<header id='header-wrapper' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/WPHeader'>
```

According to the articles, that's is the line I need to add, can someone help me with this because blogger editor is not allowed me to save the changes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<header id='header-wrapper' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/WPHeader'>
  <b:section id='header2' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
    <b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='test (Header)' type='Header' version='1'/>  
  </b:section>
</header>
```